# I want to make an image fullscreen until I scroll

Tags: html, css, image, fullscreen, muse

Here is the page I am trying to apply this full screen image to:
http://www.alexwiley.co.uk/portfolio

I wish to make it so that the image displays 100% width and 100% height until you scroll down, then you can see the content below this as you scroll.

Here is an example site of what I am looking to do:
http://www.nilsfrahm.com/

You can see his image is fullscreen until he scrolls.

I am making this website in Adobe Muse CC just as added information.

Comment: I think you can try with possition: fixed of a div that has that background;

Comment: for the record, Nils Frahm rules :D

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to use background-attachment: fixed; with background-image and background-size: cover;

Large screen version: http://codepen.io/suez/full/wulBv/

```css
* {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
       box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
div.first {
  background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/PbV1Grl.jpg");
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}
div.second {
  background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/VWYl1EC.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="first"></div>
<div class="second"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `position: fixed` to the div that has the background.